# Word-wrapping a long table cell while maintaining dynamic widths in others

Tags: css, html-table, word-wrap, column-width

I have a table which has a long line in one of its cells. I need the long line to be split so that it doesn't cause the table to be more than 100% wide. I found that by adding `table-layout: fixed` and `word-wrap: word-break`, it will wrap the long cell. However, a side effect of using `table-layout` is that it causes all columns to have the same width.

You can see an example of that here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RYdLd/2/

How can I make the first column's width auto size to fit only its contents? (i.e.  In this example, it should be just wide enough to show the `1` and `2` in that column.)

The data in the table will be loaded dynamically, so a solution which hard codes width values is not good because there's no way to know in advance how wide a column should be. My only option is to use a `<table>`, I can't use a `<div>` or some other element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#width-layout), when you use a fixed `table-layout`, the first row's column widths determine the entire table's column widths. If none of them are defined, it will distribute the column widths evenly.

Since there doesn't seem to be any other option, I ended up using the following method:

1. Loading the data in the table while the `table-layout` is set to auto.
2. Reading the width of the columns I want to be dynamic.
3. Setting those column widths to their current values.
4. Changing the `table-layout` to fixed.

Here's an example which isn't perfect (the width gets decreased by a bit):

http://jsfiddle.net/RYdLd/7/

Comment: So there's no way to do this without Javascript? sad :(

Answer (score 2):

I discovered this while wrestling with the same problem:

*Setting break-word on an element corresponds exactly to inserting a zero-width space between every character of the text contained inside that element.*

Except that this actually works with normal, dynamic tables!

This solution is very fast, since it does not require any Javascript.

(It could however be used from Javascript if desired.  Find all cells with break-word, grab all the child text nodes, and insert a zero-width space between every character.  Even then, the script would run only once during page load, so this should still be extremely performant.)

Zero-width space is `&#8203;`

Comment: This [does work](http://jsfiddle.net/RYdLd/71/) for presentation, but if a user tries copying/pasting the text (e.g. into notepad), the blank spaces will be copied as well.

Comment: Additionally [<wbr>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) will work, it behaves the same as &#8203;

Comment: Re: **Copy/Paste** these characters doesn't get copied when using Chrome 59.

Answer (score -1):

You can use: word-wrap css style to break the long sentences.

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

Comment: While this does solve the scrollbar issue, it doesn't solve the one that the question is about (i.e. the first column is still too wide): http://jsfiddle.net/RYdLd/2/

Comment: add a width attribute to the first table cell e.g: <td width="40px">1</td>

Comment: The problem is that its contents are loaded dynamically, so I don't know what width it should be.

Comment: when you don't specify a width the cells are distributed evenly(same width)

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RYdLd/4/ you can see that the first column is auto sized to fit its contents.

Comment: Cool..I was not aware of that property...thx for letting me know

Comment: Sorry... I didn't delete enough in that example, the auto size has nothing to do with `overflow-x: auto;` see this new one which has the same behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/RYdLd/5/

Comment: Thanks for the info about word-wrap, I updated the question to use `word-wrap` in order to simplify the question. As a result, this answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to handle/wrap long words in **DIV**s and **fixed tables** (*table-layout:fixed*) - just apply CSS3 *word-wrap:break-words*.

Within **dynamic tables** above property does only half of the work. We need additionally to help the browsers find break points.

A bit more detailed explanation can be found in the article [Wrap long words within dynamic tables](http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/56).